# Simplifying to least non-negative residue when modulo is not prime

Tags: modular-arithmetic, reduced-residue-system

So I am attempting to simplify $3^{252} \bmod 610$ to its least non negative residue. However $610$ is not a prime modulus and I cannot split it into a product of two prime numbers so I'm quite lost on where to begin. A hint in the right direction would suffice.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner We have gone over it briefly but I thought it was mostly used for solving congruence equations, so I'm unsure how to use it in this context.

Comment: Well, $x\equiv 3^{252}\bmod 610 $ is  a congruence.  What about Euler's theorem?

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's theorem, $3^{240}\equiv 1\bmod 610$, so $3^{252}\equiv 3^{12}\bmod 610.$

$3\equiv1\bmod2$ and $3^4\equiv1\bmod5$, so $3^{12}\equiv1\bmod 10$.

$3^5=243\equiv-1\bmod61$, so $3^{10}\equiv1\bmod61$, so $3^{12}\equiv9\bmod61$.

So $3^{252}\equiv1\bmod10$ and $3^{252}\equiv9\bmod61$.

Can you use the Chinese remainder theorem to find $3^{252}\bmod 610$?